# I am just added hamburger button in my navbar but it does not working right now?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
    <a class="navbar-brand brand" href="#">Shivaji Maskar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Fees</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>
```

Comment: Please clarify the problem and show us some code!

Comment: expected behavior vs. actual behavior?

Comment: but I have already added the code.